# Proving the identity $\csc x−\sin x = (\cot x)(\cos x) $

Tags: trigonometry

We recently started Trigonometry and I was trying to solve this.

$$\csc x − \sin x=(\cot x)(\cos x) $$

So starting with LHS:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sin x} − \sin x &= \frac{1 − (\sin x)^2}{ \sin x } \\
 &= \frac{(\cos x)^2 }{ \sin x } 
\end{align}

I am stuck now and wanted to know how should I proceed.  Is this much correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its done. Just split the numerator as:

$$ \frac{\cos x . \cos x }{\sin x}$$

$$= \frac{\cos x }{\sin x} .  \cos x $$

$$= \cot x  .  \cos x $$

Proved!

Comment: Awesome. Got it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I loved these in my precalculus class. Let's go.

You're right but went one too far. Write:

$$ \frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin x} = \cos x \cdot \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} $$

from whence the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

I'll solve it specifically

Yes, start with LHS-
$$cos\,x−sin\,x=(cot\,x)(cos\,x)$$
$$cos\,x−sin\,x=\dfrac{1}{sin\,x}-sin\,x\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\{\because cos\,x=\dfrac{1}{sin\,x}\}$$
$$=\dfrac{1-sin^2x}{sin\,x}$$$$=\dfrac{cos^2x}{sin\,x}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\{\because1-sin^2x=cos^2x\}$$
Write $cos^2x$ as-

$cos\,x\cdot cos\,x$
$$\dfrac{cos\,x\cdot cos\,x}{sin\,x}=\dfrac{cos\,x}{sin\,x}\cdot cos\,x$$
$$cot\,x\cdot cos\,x\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\{\because\dfrac{cos\,x}{sin\,x}=cot\,x\}$$